# Insert column in another table for two already imported table in Spotfire

Tags: spotfire

My question is, I’m sure, quite easy.
I have two table, including for each a column named ID.

The fist one is having all ID.
The second one is having only few.

I want to work on the missing ID.
Thus, I want to add a flag in my first table if this ID is present in the second table, or not.

I’m using Spotfire 11.4. In a previous version, it was easy to « add column » using a table from the analysis. Now I can’t find it, I have to import again the same table to make the merge.

Do you have any tips ?

**Table I**

```
| ID | Country |
| -- | ------- |
| A1 | France  |
| A2 | Germany |
| A3 | U.K.    |
| A7 | U.S.A.  |
```

**Table II**

```
| ID |
| -- |
| A2 | 
| A7 |
```

**Expected Table**

```
| ID | Country | flag | 
| -- | ------- | ---- |
| A1 | France  |   0  |
| A2 | Germany |   1  |
| A3 | U.K.    |   0  |
| A7 | U.S.A.  |   1  |
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the option is hidden in the "Other" option, when inserting column (or rows) in the data canva.